# How to convert Core ML model file to other format so it can run on a server

Tags: coreml, onnx, coremltools, onnx-coreml

A Core ML model (.mlmodel) was trained but I found it can only run on MacOS.
(But I want to run it on a Linux server)

I tried to convert it to ONNX format but failed.

`onnxmltools` and following python code was used for the conversion:

```
import onnxmltools
import coremltools

# Load a Core ML model
coreml_model = coremltools.utils.load_spec('example.mlmodel')

# Convert the Core ML model into ONNX
onnx_model = onnxmltools.convert_coreml(coreml_model, 'Example Model')

# Save as protobuf
onnxmltools.utils.save_model(onnx_model, 'example.onnx')
```

But following error message was shown after ran the program above

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convertToOnnx.py", line 8, in <module>
    onnx_model = onnxmltools.convert_coreml(coreml_model, 'Post Rating Model')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxmltools/convert/main.py", line 18, in convert_coreml
    custom_conversion_functions, custom_shape_calculators)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxmltools/convert/coreml/convert.py", line 60, in convert
    topology = parse_coreml(spec, initial_types, target_opset, custom_conversion_functions, custom_shape_calculators)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxmltools/convert/coreml/_parse.py", line 467, in parse_coreml
    topology.compile()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxconverter_common/topology.py", line 632, in compile
    self._infer_all_types()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxconverter_common/topology.py", line 508, in _infer_all_types
    operator.infer_types()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxconverter_common/topology.py", line 110, in infer_types
    registration.get_shape_calculator(self.type)(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxmltools/convert/coreml/shape_calculators/OneHotEncoder.py", line 36, in calculate_one_hot_encoder_output_shapes
    raise ValueError('Categorical indexes are missing')
ValueError: Categorical indexes are missing
```

How can I solve the error above?
Or how can I use the Core ML model on the Linux server? (Any other way of model conversion?)

Comment: I would suggest using scikit-learn or Keras to train your model instead. Core ML is useful for running models on iOS and macOS, but using it as the starting point seems to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Try Microsofts library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/convert-model-winmltools